# How to access an integer array from one C file to another?

Tags: c, arrays

I have two C files namely 'Main.c' and 'algo.c'. The `main.c` file contains an array called the `index_array` and looks as follows:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stddef.h>
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include "Main.c"

 int algo();

 int main(){
       int index_array []= {1,2,3,4,5,6};
       algo(index_array); //to call the function from the other file
       return 0;
      }
```

The other file looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int algo(int index_array){
    ///contains an algorithm to perform an operation using the array index from the Main.c file
      }
```

Now what I have a doubt is on how do I get access to the array `index_array[ ]` from the algo.c file? The way I have tried it in the alog.c file does not give me access to it. It instead gives an error saying multiple declarations of 'algo'.

Could somebody give me an idea on this please?

Comment: Hi, what are your trying is not clear. Do you have a function that takes as an argument an integer (which is associated with the index of an element of your array) or a function that takes as an argument an array (in this case you have to pass a pointer to an array of integers) ? Furthermore, why do you have two separate declartions for `algo`? Why do you have to include the `Main.c`, while you are in the `Main.c` file. Please answer the above questions and try to be more clear on what you have, what you want and where you got stuck. Thanks

Comment: Why has my question be down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach will be to change the `algo()` function signature to accept two parameters, the array itself and the size. Something like

```
 int algo(int *index_array, int size) { ....
```

That said, you should change your forward declaration to match the signature of the function definition.

Now, you can call algo from the *main.c* file like

```
 algo(index_array, sizeof(index_array)/sizeof(index_array[0]));
```

---

Note: Please remove `#include "Main.c"` from your code. Source files are *meant* to be compiled and linked together to generate the binary.

Comment: I changed the declaration the way u asked me to , but it still gives an error in the algo.c file saying multiple definitions of 'algo'..

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. But if I may ask shouldn't it work when you include the file 'Main.c' inside the algo.c file? Why does it give an error?

Comment: @Goldengirl As I mentioned , "Source files are meant to be compiled and linked together to generate the binary." Usually source files contains  definitions and if you #include them, you're most likely to get multiple definition error all the time.